# How to list other logged in devices (with IP and description) for current user in Meteor (1.3)

Tags: authentication, meteor, meteor-accounts

I would like to create something similar to Google's "Logged in devices" page for my Meteor app. How do I get the information for this?

In the Meteor `Accounts Base` package there is a method  `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()`. For me this indicated the possibility for Meteor to track these sessions per user. That's where I got this idea. Ideally I would have a description and IP-address for each logged in device.

So far I've looked into Mongo to see if there is something useful in the users database. In the `user->services->password->resume->loginTokens` array I can find logged in times and tokens. When I log in on another client there is a new entry in this array. It is removed when I log out of that client. This seems to solve part of the problem but I'm not sure this is a reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the excellent [mizzao:user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) package to achieve this.

The package adds data to the `Meteor.user()` object that lets you get things like the user's IP address, last login time, etc... There is also a `UserStatus.connections` collection that lets you query all connections on the server, including all of the current user's connections. There are even server-side event hooks for connection events so you could do things like announce *"You've just logged in on another machine at IP 123.456.789.012"*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for that!